# React Webpack Config error - You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, babel-loader

I was trying to learn about webpack I follow the instructions on the documentation but it gives me an error of.

```
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|
| render.render(
>     <React.Fragment>
|         <App/>
|     </React.Fragment>
```

here's my webpack.config.js

```
import path from 'path';

module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/App.js'),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$|jsx/,
        use: "babel-loader"
      }
    ]
```

}
};

and here's my babel config.

```
module.exports = {
    presets: [
        "@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"
    ]
}
```